# Align text to bottom of div Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Been searching for a day on this one but don't seem to find any working solution...

Currently working a webshop design in Bootstrap. The subcategory's are divs set to the height of the tallest via Jquery. They all contain an image and the category name.

I should find a way to make the name sticky to the bottom so text is somehow a bit more situated on one line, makes it eassier to read.

What I allready tried is possiotion absolut, table cell, vertical alignment,...

Since I never know the height off the divs or the images it seems kinda hard to me to fix it.

Lony way arround I can find is using Jquery to find out hight per div but this is kind off the last thing I want to do...

Anyone who has a solution? Keep in mind it's a responsive Bootstrap design, maybe their are some hidden features I don't yet know about?

Comment: Provide some html and css as well as a fiddle. That would help us and at least it will help you :)

Comment: Fiddle or Bin. I've done this before using jQuery to make the columns equal height and then the height of the div containing the image, equal height, then position:absolute of the stuff I want to stick, with padding-bottom: on the column equal to the height of the content.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the answer here contains your solution... some simple CSS positioning should handle it. [Align contents of div to the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369081/align-contents-of-div-to-the-bottom)

Comment: Not the right solution... 
This is the result: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2tk9w7uc8r1dlwn/Schermafdruk%202014-09-03%2016.36.22.png?dl=0

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle of this please?

Comment: Also, to be fair... all of that text is aligned to the bottom of those divs. Isn't that exactly what you wanted?